# Generic water-based polyurethane for concrete desk?

Tags: concrete, cement, polyurethane, sealer

I recently made a desk with a concrete top. It was a little rough so I smoothed the top with a liquid mix of just cement and water.

I'm now preparing to finish it. I have a pot of water-based polyurethane left over from a previous project. [This one.](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Varathane-1-qt-Clear-Semi-Gloss-Water-Based-Interior-Polyurethane-2-Pack-200141H/202057133?mtc=Shopping-B-F_D24-G-D24-Multi-Multi-NA-Feed-SMART-NA-NA-All_Paint_Smart&cm_mmc=Shopping-B-F_D24-G-D24-Multi-Multi-NA-Feed-SMART-NA-NA-All_Paint_Smart-71700000048001153-58700004793621602-92700041080546233&gclid=CjwKCAjwqML6BRAHEiwAdquMnQwyZxiTo_IP9QztzXZNfHozoQWqDa62UfO4gVZwOd4zP7SKhnotlhoCw0wQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) It doesn't mention masonry or concrete on the tin.

Is there any reason why this won't be appropriate for a concrete desk?

Comment: These days I'd be reluctant to use an old water-based product. They don't age well. VOCs are so low that some nasty molds or fungus will grow in them and stink irrepressably.

Comment: I can not speak to the product you have so this is a comment. I am a believer in using the **right tool/product for the job**.   https://www.everything-about-concrete.com/best-sealer-for-concrete-countertops.html  -  https://www.concretenetwork.com/products-concrete-countertops/sealer.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason to think that won't work. Urethane can be used over almost any stable, non-soluble surface. I'm a bit concerned that your surface slurry resulted in a chalky finish that might tend to lift when you apply the urethane, but the first coat should seal it in.